# Recheck image src with Ajax after page load

Tags: javascript, html, ajax, image

I have an image that will update via the server after the page has loaded. The image src is already set and will show an image, that same image path will be overwritten after initial request, I need to almost re-request the image to check the image change.

Looking at the .load function this seems the best way forward however I can't using the below isn't proving helpful. In this case image has an ID of image_id. The path to this image is absolute.

```
$( "#image_id" ).load( "ajax", function() {
  alert( "reloaded image" );
});
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You should use two different paths for the two images.

You're going to be fighting against caching in the browser and any CDNs you use. Even if you were to destroy the node and insert a new one, the old image could be shown.

More importantly, your image is not predictable. If user1 triggers the image replacement to happen, and then user2 visits the page, they'll be shown whatever image happens to be at that route at the time.